# What selector do I use to access this div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a structure like this:

```
var myThing = jQuery(
    jQuery('<div/>')
        .addClass('myTopDiv')
        .append(
            jQuery('<div/>')
                .text('some text')
                .addClass('mySecondDiv')
        ).append('<div/>')
            .text('some more text') // I WANT TO REPLACE THIS TEXT
);
```

How do I target the div which contains the text `some more text` and replace that text with new text?

I've stored it inside a variable called `myThing`, but I don't know how to navigate down to the div I want.

I can't use the classes as selectors as there are multiple instances of this variable in my application.

Something like this perhaps? Which doesn't work...

```
jQuery(
    jQuery('<tr/>')
        .text('new text')
).appendTo(myThing);
```

Comment: Share HTML and proper/full jQuery code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You stop the crazy nesting, and use variables

```
var topDiv = $('<div />', {
                'class' : 'myTopDiv'
             }),
    secDiv = $('<div />', {
                'class' : 'mySecondDiv',
                text    : 'some text'
             }),
    thrDiv = $('<div />', {
                text : 'some more text'
             });

topDiv.append(secDiv, thrDiv);

// change text

thrDiv.text('Some other text');
```

Comment: And if he has 100 of kind, than to use an array or what? Why `myThing.find('div:last')` is bad?

Comment: If he has a hundred elements, this sure is a lot cleaner than what he's currently doing, and other than a lot of writing, it's not an issue, but one generally shouldn't use javascript to generate large amounts of HTML anyway.

Comment: Cheers adeneo, this is a much better approach than mine! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe:

```
jQuery('div.myTopDiv div:last').text()
```

?

Comment: _I can't use the classes as selectors_!

Comment: In that case a fiddle would be useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$( "div:contains('John')" )
```

[According to Jquery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)  it will select the div by it's content

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code (probably because of complex nesting). check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r1h8fy9j/ for corrected one and two possible solutions for your issue:

`jQuery(myThing).find('div:last').text('text to replace to');` - in case if target div is the last one.

`jQuery(myThing).find('div').eq(1).text('text to replace to');` - in case if target div is at specific index.